# How to use Facebook Relay in a React app written in TypeScript (TSX)?

Tags: typescript, reactjs, relayjs, tsd

I would like to write a new web application in [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) that uses [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) to communicate with a [GraphQL](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/) server. Recently [JSX support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSX) was introduced for [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). But there is no typings declaration file (.d.ts) for Relay on [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/). How can I write my application in TypeScript without having to write a typings file for Relay first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript doesn't require you have typings for all the libraries you use, it's just highly recommended. To use Relay without typings:

```
import * as React from "react"
let Relay = require("react-relay")

interface HelloProps extends React.Props<HelloComponent> {
  viewer: {
    message: string
  }
}

class HelloComponent extends React.Component<HelloProps,void> {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello { this.props.viewer.message }</div>
  }
}

let Hello = Relay.createContainer(HelloComponent, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`fragment on Viewer { message }`
  }
})
```

Then use `Hello` as a regular Relay component. The idea is that `require` is a function that takes a string and returns `any` so you can then use `Relay` variable as you would in vanilla Javascript.

If you're not using Node.JS typings, you might need to add a typing for `require`. Somewhere in your d.ts files, add:

```
interface NodeRequireFunction {
  (id: string): any;
}

declare var require: NodeRequireFunction;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I need to use the Node.js typings. But now I get the following error: "error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Relay'".

Comment: `interface HelloProps extends Relay.Props<HelloComponent>` should be `interface HelloProps extends React.Props<HelloComponent>`

Comment: When I try to define a route with `class MyRoute extends Relay.Route {/* ... */}` TSC outputs `error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.`. How would you solve that error?

Comment: @Korneel, this is where you'll either need to add **some** typings or avoid using ES6 classes. Custom routes are not required to be class instances, so another alternative is just using plain objects, as seen in the first example here: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-routes.html#routes-and-queries

Comment: Thank you. It works when the route is defined as an object. Still, what would the .d.ts file with typings for Relay.Route look like? I have tried to create such a file but didn't succeed.

Comment: Here are the typings that I'm using - https://gist.github.com/guncha/c5425166a18123995898. They're pretty ad-hoc so expect things to break. You can see that the Route is just a class that takes some variables. 

Relay is changing pretty rapidly, so it might take a while until we have stable typings. Until then it's best to figure out how to write them yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really :) I had to add `var DefaultNetworkLayer;` to the typings you provided in order to be able to set de default network layer. I will definitely have to do some research on writing custom typings files.

Comment: How do you transform Relay.QL`fragment on Viewer { message }` to ES5 so the browser can understand it? The Babel Relay plugin does that, but because the TypeScript compiler already transpiles it into something different, the Babel Relay plugin doesn't transform the Relay queries so the browser throws an error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: RelayQL: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `Relay.QL`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815578/how-to-transpile-a-relay-query-from-typescript-to-es5